# how to use a variable in selenium webdriver find element by xpath?

Tags: python, webdriver

so I have a variable named folder which contains a string that I randomly generate. I want to use xpath to find this folder by name, and I am not sure how to put this into action

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[text()="variable"]')
```

where variable contains the randomized text. With sql it would be like this (select * from table where value =(?)), [variable] ...or something similar

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try this:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[text()="%s"]' % variable)
```

Comment: Sure, it's python, simple is better than complex :)